# Which back-end design choice is better for handling guest users? Storing guests as users with is_guest feild, or storing guest data on the session?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express-session

I am building an ecommerce website which should be able to handle guest checkout. When a user visits the website, they are considered "Guests" unless they register / log-in to their account.

However, even as a guest, certain information needs to be stored about that visitor (partially incase they make an account in the furture, but also just for the website to function for them) like their prefered currency, email (if provided), cart and its contents, and an order_id (if they placed an order)

My question is which of the following choices would be better for handling this?

By the way: I am using NodeJS's `express-session` in this project.

1. Creating a "User" object for all new visitors and adding the user_id to the session. In this case that user object would need a feild called `is_guest: true/false` to tell the two apart, and it would also need a `is_logged_in: true/false` feild so the front-end can tell whether to load the log-in form or the profile page because a user object would always be present.
2. Only creating a "User" object after an account has been registered through the register form, and storing all data about the cart and email ect. for guests on the session object instead.

I can see problems with both. 1) could result in a really large database if all new visitors create a user object. 2) could result in information being scattered more and the session object becoming cluttered (especially if the cart becomes large). Having never done something like this before, I would appriciate any ideas about objections or solutions to the approaches and what you think would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions are fine, and I've seen both being used.

I would guess that storing things in the database is more common. Since you will probably be logging user interactions in your database anyways, it won't take up much more data. Secondly it's slightly simpler to use the same function to render pages for logged-in and logged-out users.

If you don't use a database, you may wish to use LocalStorage instead of a cookie since there are size limits to cookies (although few carts will get large enough to reach that limit).